# Как правильно переносить интерфейсы и процедуры с функциями из delphi в python?

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

У Меня есть DLLка, к которой приложен лишь код на Делфи.
При вызове любой функции выходит ошибка к примеру "AttributeError: '_FuncPtr' object has no attribute 'GetProtoIntfVer'"
Цель какова - при помощи питона законнектиться на сервер Bimoid и сделать так сказать миниботик, но для начала надо приконнектиться к серверу, чтобы мог получать и отправлять сообщения.

```
from ctypes import *

PROTO_INTF_VERSION = 1003
obimp_lib = windll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Python\BimoidServer32\mobimp.dll")
FuncCreateObimp = obimp_lib.CreateObimp
```

Вот код на делфи, описывающий DLL:
[Ссылка на гугл диск](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11McIu_GaBl3bHEkJIMvLdY0917jKeNMp/view?usp=sharing)

Там много процедур, и сюда пытался поместить, но всё это начинает выглядеть не очень красиво, можно конечно скриншотами - но так всё будет больше весить.

UPD:
[Полный СДК, который нашёл так сказать](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMS4WQxNd-adYiIw_N4rH2MWIo5RlTyN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: не понятно на какую именно строку ругается

Comment: В случае, когда идём глубже, к примеру вызвать процедуру "Logoff()", чтобы что-нибудь попыталась вернуть. Но в итоге натыкаюсь на АттрибутЕррор

Answer (score 1):

В одном из питоновких скриптов (site-packages\zmq\utils\win32.py) нашел такое использование:

```
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, DWORD

kernel32 = windll.LoadLibrary('kernel32')

# <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016.aspx>
PHANDLER_ROUTINE = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, DWORD)
SetConsoleCtrlHandler = kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler
SetConsoleCtrlHandler.argtypes = (PHANDLER_ROUTINE, BOOL)
SetConsoleCtrlHandler.restype = BOOL
```

Так же может посмотрите _link_library(), getattr(). Судя по тому, что в obimp_dll.pas всюду написано stdcall, проблем не должно быть. А вот с interface не знаю. Вообще в obimp_dll.pas нет кода как такового, только описание типов и несколько констант.

Comment: Я могу полностью архив так же на Гугл диск закинуть, с применением уже данных функций.